# Get inputs of parent form jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a form which has all inputs disabled. There's also a button within that form which, if clicked, is supposed to enable the inputs.
I know how to disable and enable the inputs using something like this:
`$('#form :input'):prop('disabled',false)`.

This is all fine but I'd like to have an implementation that is abstract enough to work in all forms that have such a toggle button. Therefore I tried this:

```
$('.toggle-btn').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('form :input').prop('disabled','false');
}
```

But it's not working.

I'm looking for a way to access input fields of a form when it's selected as a parent. Does anyone know how to go about it?

Comment: What's not working about it? What is the actual behaviour compared to the expected?

Comment: Dot, not colon: `$(this).parents('form :input').prop('disabled','false');`

Comment: I think it should be `$(this).parents('form').find(':input').prop('disabled',false);`

Comment: Can you share your code in fiddle as don't clear what a problem you have.

Comment: @Satpal - Thank you, that was it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) function with [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) if your `input` is directly in your `form` , Try this for example:

```
$('.toggle-btn').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find(':input').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

If the `input` is in other elements that are inside your `form`, you need to use the jQuery [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) function like this:

```
$('.toggle-btn').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('form').find(':input').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Satpal's solution works slightly better for me but this is a good answer, too

Comment: @Satpal But it is correct, what is incorrect in the answer?

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni, 1. Its should be `parents()`/`closest()` the method `parent()` will always find immediate parent one level up 2. `'false' !== false`

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni, In html  as `<form><input type="text" disabled />
  <div>
  <input type="button" class="toggle-btn" />  </div> t
</form>` the above code will not work

Comment: @Satpal Thanks for your comments, I will update the answer now.

Comment: @mplungjan I think I was the first one to answer this, the edit added more info to the answer, but it was correct from the beginning :) After all, the purpose of SO is to help fixing issues not to collect reputation, and I think both answers will add value to this magnificent site. Thanks all

Comment: Your first answer had two errors. `parent.find` and `,"false"`  I was busy writing a working example to be the first to post an answer but I was the first to post a correction (comment) and the first to post a CORRECT answer. Also I believe my answer to be more complete with more explanations on what was wrong... Your first example will fail if the button is wrapped in anything. Satpal's comment was the first correct comment

Answer (score 1):

1. it is `false` not `"false"` - `"false"` is truthy
2. you need `find()` and `.closest()` which in my opinion is better than parent(s) since it does not care if the button is wrapped in anything
3. you need `.prop` and not `:prop`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle-btn').on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("form").find(":input").prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <input type="button" class="toggle-btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: I needed to find ':input' to accomodate for textareas and selects